# How to analyse cross-cultural similarity in groups with very different responses?

Tags: spss

There are 40 audio files (classical music) and a choice is given to select an answer among 9 emotions. Out of these 40 audio files I compute 8 variables and these variables are connected to the 9 emotions. I have 3 different cultural groups of participants. I run the case summaries but there is hardly any agreement among the selected emotions, among the groups. I need to know what kind of tests (or model) I should run for understanding whether or not these audio files elicit responses which have any cross-cultural similarity. The audio files are supposed to be eliciting specific (fixed) emotions. I am using SPSS.

> "Cultural group x is more likely than group y to associate a certain
>   variable a (derived from the audio files) with emotion e." (Robert)

Comment: What are the variables?

Comment: The 8 variables are the melodic modes that are associated with the emotions.

Comment: Is it one category variable with 9 categories and thus 8 dummy variables?

Comment: Each audio file belongs to a melodic mode which is associated with an emotion. The participant has to select one emotion from those 9 emotions (possible answers).

Comment: What do you mean by “case analysis” and “hardly any agreement among the selected emotions, among the groups”. Isn't that your answer, right there?

Comment: Case summaries, I meant, sorry.

Comment: Still, what's that precisely?

Comment: In SPSS (Analyze>Reports>Case Summaries) reports for each variable frequencies, percentage, number of cases, etc. The Summarize procedure calculates subgroup statistics for variables within categories of one or more grouping variables. All levels of the grouping variable are crosstabulated. You can choose the order in which the statistics are displayed. Summary statistics for each variable across all categories are also displayed. Data values in each category can be listed or suppressed. With large data sets, you can choose to list only the first n cases.

Comment: And what makes you think there is hardly any agreement? The most frequent emotion for each clip in different groups?

Comment: Yes, the most frequent emotion for each clip in different groups is always different.

Comment: Then I am not sure what a test would add to this, you already have got considerable evidence that cross-cultural similarity is minimal (note that with facial expressions what counts as evidence of in-group advantage is a slightly better “recognition rate” for stimuli originating from the same group compared to other groups but the most common choice is still generally the same).

Comment: Thank you. In this case, the recognition rate is minimal even in the group for which the stimuli are supposed to be familiar.

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly how to interpret all this without more information (for example a full confusion matrix) but if your stimuli don't even convey a clear affective meaning in any group and the answer appear random, why even wonder about testing or cross-cultural similarity? Also, if there is no unambiguously correct interpretation, it might be best to avoid the word “recognition” (in fact, it might be best to avoid in any case and simply speak of “interpretation”) but the point remains.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you have hypotheses such as

> Cultural group `x` is more likely than group `y` to associate a certain variable `a` (derived from the audio files) with emotion `e`.

Then you could use [**linear regression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to find out which cultural group associates which audio-derived variables with which emotion(s).

The variable you want to **explain** (dependent variable) is `emotion`.
The variables that can be used in the model (independent variables) to do the explaining are `cultural group` and your eight variables derived from the audio recordings.

I have never used SPSS, but I'm sure it offers one or more techniques for model selection. If the cultural groups differ in the ways they associate emotions with recordings there will be (an) interaction(s) between `cultural group` and one or more of the variables derived from the recordings.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. Yes, you understood correctly. I shall use the linear regression model. I cannot vote up your answer since my reputation is below 15. I wish I could.

Comment: The response seems to be in checklist format (pick an emotion from the list) so one multinomial variable or possibly 9 dichotomous responses. Linear regression does not seem particularly appropriate. Plus you are not providing any clue as to how to handle the groups (aggregate the responses to each clip? hierarchical model?)

Comment: Yes, the response is in checklist format; one response out of 9. I am not understanding "(aggregate the responses to each clip? hierarchical model?)"

Comment: @GaëlLaurans, DS1 indicated that he derived eight variables *from* the drop-down emotion list. This is why I suggested linear regression. I agree that if the drop-down emotion list is to be used as independent variables linear regression wouldn't be that useful.

Comment: I don't think we agree with each other, in fact my point was the exact opposite: If you have eight predictors/independent variables (of any kind, including dummy variables to represent an emotion choice) and a quantitative response, linear regression might in fact be useful but that's not the case here. The emotion category is the response.

Comment: Sorry, brief moment of confusion, ignore my previous comment. `emotion` is the independent variables, and it's categorical. Why do you think regression is not a good way of modelling that? What alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: @robert Again, my point is that emotion is *not* the independent variable!